# How to query the parent entity of a paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

I would like to use the entityQuery for querying paragraphs

- of type `my_paragraph_type`
- With the field `field_boolean_test` set to TRUE
- And a condition on the parent of the paragraph: `field_parent` must be set

Here is my try, but it is not working

```
Drupal::entityQuery('paragraph')
  ->condition('type', 'my_paragraph_type')
  ->exists('parent_id.entity:node.field_parent') //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
  ->condition('field_boolean_test', TRUE)
  ->execute();
```

The parent is a node and the paragraphs are attached to a field named `field_paragraphs`

Comment: AFAIK the `.entity:entity_type.` notation in entity queries is a feature of "real" entity reference fields. The `parent_id` of paragraph entities is defined as a string, not an entity reference field, so this syntax will not work by concept. You have to write a database query, with manual joining, etc

Comment: Thank you. Any help available on how to write this kind of database query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the entity query you can get all the node ids with your desired conditions, because the entity reference fields are deposited there.
For the other direction you need to do a custom database query like the following:

```
$query = \Drupal::database()->select('paragraphs_item', 'pi');
$query->fields('pi', ['id']);
// Join the field which references the paragraph item to the node.
$query->join('node__field_parent', 'fpc', 'fpc.field_parent_target_id = pi.id');
// Join the field_boolean_test field from the paragraph.
$query->join('paragraph__field_boolean_test', 'fbt', 'fbt.entity_id = pi.id');
// Join the node field data table for conditions on the status for example.
$query->join('node_field_data', 'nfd', 'nfd.nid = fpc.entity_id');
// Join the field_parent field from the node.
$query->join('node_field_parent', 'nfp', 'nfp.nid = fpc.entity_id');
// Add the required conditions.
$query->condition('pi.type', 'my_paragraph_type');
$query->condition('fbt.field_boolean_test_value', TRUE);
$query->condition('nfp.field_parent_value', TRUE); // You can also leave this condition, because the join requires a database entry.
// Get the paragraph ids.
$paragraph_ids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```